# How to travel with a minor when you're not their parent?

Tags: air-travel, legal, international-travel, children, minors

I have a friend travelling and he will be taking his goddaughter to Disneyland Paris. She is a minor.

What kind of documentation does he need to travel with her? (He is not officially her tutor or anything like that.)

He will travel inside Europe from Portugal and will travel through Brussels (destination airport).

Answer (score 10):

There are specific requirements per country in EU. EasyJet has [a good page](https://www.easyjet.com/en/help/boarding-and-flying/flying-with-children) on that.

Note that minors (< 18 yo) flying from Portugal are covered by one of the specific entries in the page I linked.

UPDATE: Starting from 15 JAN 2017, a [specific authorization](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F1359) is required for French minors, when the leave the French territory without one of their parents (or the legal representative)

Comment: And as per this question https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/110255/6188 just a few hours after your edit, we find out that easyJet hasn't updated their website to the lament of that question's OP

Answer (score 7):

You didn't specify nationality although it doesn't matter much: you need a letter signed by

> every non-accompanying person or organization with the legal right to make major decisions for the child

from http://travel.gc.ca/travelling/children/consent-letter . This page has links to handy letters you can fill out, sign and carry.

Comment: Do those need to be officially recognised? Or the signature is enough? would a copy of the parents Id be needed? thanks.

Answer (score 5):

When I sent my minor children abroad alone, I always gave them notarized letters of consent.  No official at any American or European border ever asked to see any documentation beyond their passport.

I would treat this situation as the girl traveling alone -- having an adult "with her" in some official capacity would make the situation more complicated -- and if I did persist with the letter, add the godfather under "contact information".

I would also consider giving a medical power of attorney to the godparent, just in case of either real medical emergency or some over-eager border guard questioning a man traveling with an unrelated teen-aged girl.