# I wish to travel from UK to France with a minor who is not one of my family. What documentation do I need?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, france, minors

I wish to travel on holiday from UK to France - and back -  with family members and a minor who is not one of my family. I have the parents' consent. The minor, like me, is British and has a UK passport.

What documentation do I need? The UK government [advises](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/france/entry-requirements) checking the France government website, which fortunately contains an option to translate into English, but it is still not quite clear what documentation will be required.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42805/how-to-travel-with-a-minor-when-youre-not-their-parent?rq=1

Comment: https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F1359/personnalisation/resultat?quest0=1&quest1=2&quest=&lang=en indicates that in your case, you don't need an AST for the French side of the journey, either in or out.

Comment: you need a written consent from parents, stamped in notary... if you want to be 100% you will not have problems

Comment: @audionuma that would seem to be the actual answer.  Perhaps you should post it as an answer?

Comment: I've no idea what the law says, but when we took my 15-year old daughter and a friend of hers on holiday to France, no one asked for anything more than a passport.

Comment: There's a big gap between what you're required to provide in order to be 100% safe - which is answered below, and what you're likely to need in practice - which is nothing.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### You need letters of permission from anyone with parental responsibility

Abduction of children is a thing; international abduction is more serious because legal systems differ between countries, and cross-border enforcement of court orders for child custody and support is extremely difficult. Airlines and a country's exit immigration officers are sometimes very sensitive, and may ask about permission.

Thus, you [should](https://www.gov.uk/permission-take-child-abroad) carry written statements from both of the child's parents, or the parent who has sole custody and control, identifying the child, and identifying you, and stating that you have permission to take the child from the departure airport and country to a specific destination. Contact details for the parents should be provided to allow quick verification if required. Template letters can be drafted from a [reputable legal template](https://www.lawdepot.co.uk/contracts/child-travel-consent/?webuser_data_id=144141033).

The [rules for Portugal are stricter but otherwise this answer would apply when travelling from UK to any EU country](https://www.easyjet.com/en/help/boarding-and-flying/travel-documents-and-information). The French have some rules for French children leaving the territory, but [these do not apply to the case above](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F1359/personnalisation/resultat?quest0=1&quest1=2&quest=&lang=en) as the family and accompanying minor are British tourists.

If you're asked, and you cannot provide such written evidence, the child (and probably you) won't be allowed to board the flight or whatever means of transport is chosen.

Comment: The german automobil club offers *Travel authorization for children* forms in multiple languages (but not the combination english/french), so you might want to look at what the corresponding British or French clubs offer.[Reisevollmacht für Kinder | ADAC](https://www.adac.de/reise-freizeit/ratgeber/reiserecht/reisevollmacht-kinder/)

Comment: Might it need to be notarized? Or help

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- At the bottom of the form there is a box with: *Raum für amtliche Vermerke* (Room for official notes), which is where such a notarization would be placed. Copy of passports page of the Parents/guardians and contact information would then leave no questions open. [Reisevollmacht für alleinreisendes Kind (Deutsch-Englisch ; German/English)](https://res.cloudinary.com/adacde/image/upload/v1571649306/ADAC-eV/KOR/Text/PDF/reisevollmacht-englisch_kutovt.pdf)

Comment: @MarkJohnson I was addressing David, but good to know for Germany.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Notarization will certainly help to demonstrate that a permission letter is genuine. Whether notarization is actually required will depend upon the rules of the organization or entity examining the letter (here, the UK Border Force, and Eurostar or whatever airline is being used) and how assiduously that organization or entity applies its rules...if it even has such rules.

Comment: *flight or Eurostar* — or, of course, the ferry or shuttle (private automobiles remain an extremely popular way of travel).

Comment: The written statements should also be time-bound (specify start and end dates). Leave some leeway for travel incidents.

Comment: Wait - is this "general wise advice" (to which anyone would agree).  Or is this an answer based on facts / sources??  Example of source materiel https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F1359/personnalisation/resultat?quest0=1&quest1=2&quest=&lang=en

Comment: @Fattie That source is about an 'Authorisation to leave the territory' of France, which is not the OP's situation.

Comment: @gerrit Thanks, you're right. I've amended the answer.

Comment: @MarkJohnson ah so it means the **child** is **French** (but a parent is a foreigner) .. ?

Comment: It would seem there is **no information** on what (if anything) is demanded by the authorities in either of the two countries.

Answer (score -1):

### Depending on the age of the child they could fly "on their own".

Whilst looking into the documentation needed you may find that the documents needed for a minor to fly on their own are simpler/easier to complete/obtain than the one's necessary to fly with a non-guardian.

Comment: Pretending that the child is travelling alone sounds like deceiving the authorities, which might be a bad idea?  And of course, this only works with public transport (or maybe bicycle on ferry, if the minor is old enough for that to be a reasonable alternative), not if OP is travelling by car.

Comment: If they are of legal age to travel on their own then make that official arrangement. You may then happen to talk/eat/interact with them but that doesn't change the official arrangement the minor has. But yes if travelling by car this doesn't work.