# How to travel with a minor when you're not their parent (returning to residence country)?

Tags: air-travel, legal

A few years ago, I made the [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42805/how-to-travel-with-a-minor-when-youre-not-their-parent). This focused on going out. However, I have doubts when returning to home country.

I will be flying with a family member, who is a minor. I know I need a written consent from the parents. That's fine. But, my doubt is when returning to the home country. Do I need any authorization? I guess not, since the minor and I will be returning. Still, I would like to be sure. Is there a common rule, or would this change from country to country?

Comment: Probably specific to the country. Where are the consenting parents? Bringing back a minor to the parents should pose no problems.

Comment: If you have consent from the guardians, it is not a problem. Many minors "travel unaccompanied" (which really means that airlines will escort them), without problems. Note: check entry country requirements: sometime it is better if parents will fill the form and sign it (and send it to you).

Comment: It needs to be clear that the minor lives in the country you're returning to. If you have permission for taking them out, then you could show that; if you have proof of their residence that would help (not sure what residence documents a child has); even a return ticket might help. It's possible for a child to have a passport or birth certificate for one country while living with a parent in another country, so it might look like abduction if you can't prove their residence or outward journey.